# How to draw an eagle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, svg, inkscape

I would like to draw an eagle with TiKz, with one continuous curve. The eagle can be simpler, but basically like this with symmetric wings.

The tikz code is needed to replace the bird below with the eagle

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.55]
    \clip(0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);


\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](0,-1)--(0,5);

\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](-2,2.35)--++(4,0);
    \draw[thick](0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);

\newcommand\bird[1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \filldraw (0,0) --%
        (10,-5) -- (19,8) -- (35,7) -- (38,-12) -- (60,0) --%
        (75,23) -- (80,40) -- (52,37) -- (74,50) -- (52,50) -- (60,60)--%
        (38,48) -- (35,67) -- (19,68) -- (10,55) -- (0,60) --%
        (-8,50) -- (14,50) -- (-8,37) -- (20,40) -- (15,23) -- cycle;
        \begin{scope}[draw=gray]
            \draw (35,15) -- +(-25:25) (40,20) -- +(-20:25) (42,25) -- +(-15:25) (40,30) -- +(-10:30);
            \draw (1,55) circle (1);
            \draw[clip] (24,55) circle (4);
            \filldraw[gray] (27,52) circle (4);
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
}

\bird{shift={(.7,.7)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};
\bird{shift={(-1.5,.7)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};

\bird{shift={(.7,3)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};
\bird{shift={(-1.5,3)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};

    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why? That is, why in tikz?

Comment: Yes, since the arm coat is used in several color options, tikz is needed.

Comment: There is a package named `worldflags` on CTAN. It contains all of the world's flags done  in TikZ. I am sure there is a suitable eagle in all these flags and coats of arms somewhere …

Comment: No, no such arms coats in the worldflags, just in here 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armorial_of_sovereign_states

Comment: Have you taken a look at the actual package? There is TikZ code for the German and Austrian vexillological eagles in there, not to mention the provincial flags of Upper and Lower Austria, Burgenland and the Tyrol, all of which contain an eagle of sorts.

Comment: Here is a procedure how you can do it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685905/245790 . Where I used separate \draw commands, you can draw just one path instead by dropping subsequent `; \draw` codes.

Comment: BTW: your posted code can't compile. Please make it a habbit, to provide code, which compiles (and please correct this one). Thank you

Comment: It is possible to export paths to Ti*k*Z format via Inkscape. Maybe this is the way to go here. If you don't have a vectorised format of the eagle, you need to draw the paths first, of course. Some graphics editing software should be able to trace the paths for you. But actually, what is wrong with your solution? =)

Comment: You could also look on open clipart's successor site. You can download SVG there and turn it into a `pic` with customisation options. I created on of my TeX donkeys that way. (Actually, all of my TeX donkeys, but the Don keys didn't work so well out-of-the-box.)

Comment: have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172336/140722

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. (Or use the alternative way of [digitizing manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685897/how-to-draw-this-with-tikz/685905#685905).)

#### Preparations:

- use a drawing program like Paint.net to remove background (inverted mask)
- and to turn everything into black, including the gray circles top right
- use a program like inkscape to turn it into SVG

In fact, I used a program from the Apple world, which allowed some simplification of the path during conversion. You could turn the SVG-path into Tikz syntax, but for what purpose? There are enough tools, both on- and offline, which allow editing such SCG-pathes. // If the code is too long, move the pic-part into a file and `\input` it. // See also [tag svg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg) here.

#### Tikz

- define a `pic`-style, which just includes the SVG-path
- place `\pic`s, just like you'd place nodes
- make sure to `yscale=-1` to account for the different coordinate systems
- I used one of the birdies to scale them smaller for demonstration purposes

Left to do: fill the SVG path.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepgflibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    eagl/.pic={
        \pgfpathsvg{M158 42C165.438 42.7346 177.541 42.7897 179 53C172.229 51.8259 166.098 48.1681 160 45C161.657 51.8904 168.056 57.1405 174 61C172.5 66 172.5 66 171 71C174.5 70 174.5 70 178 69C180.941 73.2713 178.304 79.9347 175.625 84.375C174.325 86.5304 171.208 86.7917 169 88C171.119 95.415 174.676 94.7989 182 95C180.948 97.5417 181.024 100.948 178.844 102.625C176.168 104.683 172.281 104.208 169 105C170 109 170 109 171 113C164.5 112 164.5 112 158 111C159 116.5 159 116.5 160 122C153.174 118.295 145.577 116.483 146.219 105.812C147.067 91.7053 152.957 78.2736 154.438 64.2188C154.742 61.3293 154.2 57.0048 151.465 56.025C141.953 52.6177 130.947 55.6094 121.375 52.375C115.586 50.4189 111.792 44.7917 107 41C106 49.5 106 49.5 105 58C76.9824 57.892 48.7326 58.9877 21 55C23.9167 62.0729 25.8489 69.6374 29.75 76.2188C32.0824 80.1537 34.8458 85.3596 39.375 86C61.3671 89.1095 83.7917 86.6667 106 87C104.75 88.1667 103.901 90.0534 102.25 90.5C87.9796 94.3609 73.5121 97.6753 58.875 99.75C46.6848 101.478 34.2917 101.167 22 101.875C24.6065 110.814 24.9173 123.443 37.125 126.031C48.9588 128.54 61.2913 128.315 73.375 127.75C83.0366 127.299 92.4583 124.583 102 123C101.208 124 100.797 125.496 99.625 126C81.335 133.863 62.9397 141.582 44.0625 147.906C37.9586 149.951 31.3542 149.969 25 151C38.6532 166.079 47.2183 177.714 68.875 170C80.8682 165.728 92.2917 160 104 155C103.167 156.542 102.861 158.52 101.5 159.625C83.7074 174.069 66.0497 188.823 46.875 201.375C40.8042 205.349 33.2292 206.312 26.4062 208.781C32.2218 216.712 44.0952 234.239 57.5938 225.75C75.9297 214.218 91.8646 199.25 109 186C73 228.5 73 228.5 37 271C42.6667 273.333 47.8748 277.806 54 278C59.2282 278.166 65.0487 275.931 68.5 272C89.4599 248.129 106.833 221.333 126 196C113.526 228.812 104.825 264.031 85 293C98.4247 290.637 106.026 292.963 112.719 279.219C125.449 253.075 135.573 225.74 147 199C147 219.292 138.125 238.654 132 258C140.24 255.001 146.563 254.077 151 244.25C158.277 228.134 162.333 210.75 168 194C169.698 201.115 174.232 208.119 173.094 215.344C171.702 224.175 164.033 230.855 160.875 239.219C156.239 251.495 154.132 264.609 149.812 277C148.49 280.794 142.089 280.568 140 284C138.299 286.795 140.904 291.183 138.875 293.75C132.346 302.012 124.032 308.828 115.5 315C110.14 318.878 104.062 307.901 97.625 306.375C87.0707 303.874 81.5544 317.005 80 324C82.5 322.792 84.7234 320.403 87.5 320.375C89.5003 320.355 90.3879 323.644 92.375 323.875C96.6616 324.373 101.636 322.084 105.312 324.344C99.2025 335.74 83.5004 333.675 83 348.5C82.8474 353.02 82.7449 357.856 84.625 361.969C85.6703 364.255 88.875 364.656 91 366C90.75 358.5 90.75 358.5 90.5 351C93.32 350.867 96.8073 352.427 98.96 350.6C102.976 347.193 103.239 340.686 107 337C109.403 334.645 116.67 333.631 117.094 336.969C117.725 341.941 116.001 347.045 116.75 352C117.168 354.764 120.306 356.712 120.5 359.5C120.749 363.089 118.833 366.5 118 370C126.227 367.999 132.476 357.951 133 349.5C133.38 343.365 129.125 337.833 127.188 332C132.395 334.299 138.354 335.729 144 335C144.5 340.5 144.5 340.5 145 346C149.401 337.763 145.865 327.151 144 318C137.793 318.266 137.793 318.266 131.586 318.531C137.349 313.521 142.028 306.882 148.875 303.5C152.502 301.708 156.958 303.833 161 304C161.643 290.66 172.342 279.574 180.5 269C185.27 286.172 164.997 307.201 158.625 320.688C156.57 325.038 168.213 322.484 173 322C171.968 337.485 163.191 349.511 154 361C160.01 359.323 167.214 359.936 172.031 355.969C179.229 350.041 182.677 340.656 188 333C187.313 342.146 184.707 351.349 185.938 360.438C186.934 367.795 191.646 374.146 194.5 381C197 374.708 200.976 368.817 202 362.125C203.519 352.199 202 342.042 202 332C206.833 339.833 210.734 348.326 216.5 355.5C221.707 361.978 227.01 360.732 234 361C226.538 348.614 220.272 335.466 215 322C220.643 322.615 227.011 323.708 232 321C226.375 312.292 219.954 304.049 215.125 294.875C211.053 287.14 205.717 277.787 208.5 269.5C215.333 277.5 223.823 284.341 229 293.5C230.73 296.561 228.333 300.5 228 304C231.958 303.792 236.287 301.69 239.875 303.375C246.405 306.442 251.23 312.319 256.406 317.344C257.057 317.976 256.802 319.115 257 320C256.141 319.848 246.574 316.45 244.625 320.375C241.996 325.668 239.101 331.341 239.188 337.25C239.239 340.751 243.063 343.083 245 346C245 340.5 245 340.5 245 335C248.75 336.25 248.75 336.25 252.5 337.5C256.556 331.127 253.519 333.655 263 332C260.75 338.458 256.931 344.57 256.25 351.375C256.016 353.713 259.627 354.818 260.5 357C261.762 360.156 260.364 364.356 262.5 367C264.388 369.337 268.167 369 271 370C270.125 366.854 268.022 363.809 268.375 360.562C268.699 357.584 272.509 355.755 272.875 352.781C273.392 348.583 269.919 344.371 270.875 340.25C271.635 336.975 278.31 332.383 281.5 336.5C284.617 340.522 284.769 346.68 288.625 350C291.418 352.405 295.875 351.333 299.5 352C300.195 361.037 301.139 356.649 296 365C307.887 370.349 305.736 345.51 305.406 343.125C304.187 334.302 288.826 330.941 283 324C291.774 322.375 287.804 321.546 295 326C298.875 322.734 298.875 322.734 302.75 319.469C305.875 322.234 305.875 322.234 309 325C307.612 318.061 303.004 304.117 292.125 306.406C285.71 307.756 280.124 318.025 274.375 314.875C260.287 307.155 247.255 299.206 249 283C232.566 280.902 237.012 264.718 231.625 249.375C226.898 235.911 218.57 223.682 215.344 209.781C214.194 204.827 217.425 197.864 222.216 196.157C227.769 212.438 232.452 229.042 238.875 245C242.328 253.578 248.342 254.4 256 258C251.083 240.75 245.323 223.718 241.25 206.25C240.803 204.333 242.146 202.417 242.594 200.5C254.385 228.073 264.613 256.369 277.969 283.219C283.49 294.318 294.199 292.144 304 293C284.006 264.522 275.251 229.568 263 197C282.917 222.479 301.997 248.635 322.75 273.438C331.108 283.427 344.091 274.901 352 271C325.938 244.194 303.382 214.173 280 185C298.58 198.142 316.443 212.362 335.739 224.428C351.643 234.373 358.103 218.902 364 208C355.896 205.208 346.931 204.208 339.688 199.625C321.369 188.036 304.92 173.704 288.125 160C286.602 158.757 286.042 156.667 285 155C303.875 161.167 322.469 168.272 341.625 173.5C353.216 176.663 361.04 156.397 364 151C339.166 146.764 315.257 137.515 292.25 127.25C290.42 126.434 289.417 124.417 288 123C308.196 125.805 346.101 137.738 362 116.375C365.284 111.962 366 106.125 368 101C338.406 101.51 308.955 101.736 282 87C303.667 87 325.462 89.3591 347 87C351.219 86.5379 354.472 82.3929 356.75 78.8125C361.626 71.151 364.25 62.2708 368 54C344.666 59.4084 320.119 59.5949 296.24 57.72C291.741 57.3667 286.752 56.319 283.471 53.22C280.768 50.6665 282.625 43.8286 279 43C274.148 61.2227 252.903 53.2314 238.475 55.4675C236.915 55.7093 235.959 57.707 235.625 59.25C230.162 84.5018 258.723 104.327 229 122C230.219 113.391 230.219 113.391 231.438 104.781C214.208 101.693 215.936 93.3421 227 83C222.159 81.3521 215.468 76.8958 216.438 71.875C217.468 66.5388 224.583 63.4188 225 58C217.926 57.0569 220.332 58.8815 217.156 53.4688C220.438 49.9792 225.147 47.4171 227 43C228.676 39.0039 227 34.3333 227 30C210.772 45.8511 204.706 20.4146 191 26.5C188.089 27.7927 188.314 33.5116 185.18 34.08C174.913 35.9417 159.82 23.7982 158 42Z}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }% end of pic-definition
    ]% end of options
    
    
    \pic[yscale=-1] at ( 0, 0) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1] at (15, 0) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1] at ( 0,15) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1,scale=0.3] at (15,15) {eagl};    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}



% ~~~ posted code ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.55]
    \clip(0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);


\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](0,-1)--(0,5);

\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](-2,2.35)--++(4,0);
    \draw[thick](0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);

\newcommand\bird[1]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
        \filldraw (0,0) --%
        (10,-5) -- (19,8) -- (35,7) -- (38,-12) -- (60,0) --%
        (75,23) -- (80,40) -- (52,37) -- (74,50) -- (52,50) -- (60,60)--%
        (38,48) -- (35,67) -- (19,68) -- (10,55) -- (0,60) --%
        (-8,50) -- (14,50) -- (-8,37) -- (20,40) -- (15,23) -- cycle;
        \begin{scope}[draw=gray]
            \draw (35,15) -- +(-25:25) (40,20) -- +(-20:25) (42,25) -- +(-15:25) (40,30) -- +(-10:30);
            \draw (1,55) circle (1);
            \draw[clip] (24,55) circle (4);
            \filldraw[gray] (27,52) circle (4);
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
}

\bird{shift={(.7,.7)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};
\bird{shift={(-1.5,.7)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};

\bird{shift={(.7,3)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};
\bird{shift={(-1.5,3)}, fill=yellow!33, scale=.013};

    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### P.S.

Wrt. the comment, here's a slightly different way to do it, see ch. 14.11 "The SVG Operation". Kindly check the indicated differences.

*Searching this site AND reading manuals is still a strong solvent ...*

[image: result2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}% <<<
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    eagl/.pic={
        % ~~~ the beginning is different now ~~~~~~~~~~~
        \filldraw [fill=blue] (0,0)  svg{M158 42C165.438 42.7346 177.541 42.7897 179 53C172.229 51.8259 166.098 48.1681 160 45C161.657 51.8904 168.056 57.1405 174 61C172.5 66 172.5 66 171 71C174.5 70 174.5 70 178 69C180.941 73.2713 178.304 79.9347 175.625 84.375C174.325 86.5304 171.208 86.7917 169 88C171.119 95.415 174.676 94.7989 182 95C180.948 97.5417 181.024 100.948 178.844 102.625C176.168 104.683 172.281 104.208 169 105C170 109 170 109 171 113C164.5 112 164.5 112 158 111C159 116.5 159 116.5 160 122C153.174 118.295 145.577 116.483 146.219 105.812C147.067 91.7053 152.957 78.2736 154.438 64.2188C154.742 61.3293 154.2 57.0048 151.465 56.025C141.953 52.6177 130.947 55.6094 121.375 52.375C115.586 50.4189 111.792 44.7917 107 41C106 49.5 106 49.5 105 58C76.9824 57.892 48.7326 58.9877 21 55C23.9167 62.0729 25.8489 69.6374 29.75 76.2188C32.0824 80.1537 34.8458 85.3596 39.375 86C61.3671 89.1095 83.7917 86.6667 106 87C104.75 88.1667 103.901 90.0534 102.25 90.5C87.9796 94.3609 73.5121 97.6753 58.875 99.75C46.6848 101.478 34.2917 101.167 22 101.875C24.6065 110.814 24.9173 123.443 37.125 126.031C48.9588 128.54 61.2913 128.315 73.375 127.75C83.0366 127.299 92.4583 124.583 102 123C101.208 124 100.797 125.496 99.625 126C81.335 133.863 62.9397 141.582 44.0625 147.906C37.9586 149.951 31.3542 149.969 25 151C38.6532 166.079 47.2183 177.714 68.875 170C80.8682 165.728 92.2917 160 104 155C103.167 156.542 102.861 158.52 101.5 159.625C83.7074 174.069 66.0497 188.823 46.875 201.375C40.8042 205.349 33.2292 206.312 26.4062 208.781C32.2218 216.712 44.0952 234.239 57.5938 225.75C75.9297 214.218 91.8646 199.25 109 186C73 228.5 73 228.5 37 271C42.6667 273.333 47.8748 277.806 54 278C59.2282 278.166 65.0487 275.931 68.5 272C89.4599 248.129 106.833 221.333 126 196C113.526 228.812 104.825 264.031 85 293C98.4247 290.637 106.026 292.963 112.719 279.219C125.449 253.075 135.573 225.74 147 199C147 219.292 138.125 238.654 132 258C140.24 255.001 146.563 254.077 151 244.25C158.277 228.134 162.333 210.75 168 194C169.698 201.115 174.232 208.119 173.094 215.344C171.702 224.175 164.033 230.855 160.875 239.219C156.239 251.495 154.132 264.609 149.812 277C148.49 280.794 142.089 280.568 140 284C138.299 286.795 140.904 291.183 138.875 293.75C132.346 302.012 124.032 308.828 115.5 315C110.14 318.878 104.062 307.901 97.625 306.375C87.0707 303.874 81.5544 317.005 80 324C82.5 322.792 84.7234 320.403 87.5 320.375C89.5003 320.355 90.3879 323.644 92.375 323.875C96.6616 324.373 101.636 322.084 105.312 324.344C99.2025 335.74 83.5004 333.675 83 348.5C82.8474 353.02 82.7449 357.856 84.625 361.969C85.6703 364.255 88.875 364.656 91 366C90.75 358.5 90.75 358.5 90.5 351C93.32 350.867 96.8073 352.427 98.96 350.6C102.976 347.193 103.239 340.686 107 337C109.403 334.645 116.67 333.631 117.094 336.969C117.725 341.941 116.001 347.045 116.75 352C117.168 354.764 120.306 356.712 120.5 359.5C120.749 363.089 118.833 366.5 118 370C126.227 367.999 132.476 357.951 133 349.5C133.38 343.365 129.125 337.833 127.188 332C132.395 334.299 138.354 335.729 144 335C144.5 340.5 144.5 340.5 145 346C149.401 337.763 145.865 327.151 144 318C137.793 318.266 137.793 318.266 131.586 318.531C137.349 313.521 142.028 306.882 148.875 303.5C152.502 301.708 156.958 303.833 161 304C161.643 290.66 172.342 279.574 180.5 269C185.27 286.172 164.997 307.201 158.625 320.688C156.57 325.038 168.213 322.484 173 322C171.968 337.485 163.191 349.511 154 361C160.01 359.323 167.214 359.936 172.031 355.969C179.229 350.041 182.677 340.656 188 333C187.313 342.146 184.707 351.349 185.938 360.438C186.934 367.795 191.646 374.146 194.5 381C197 374.708 200.976 368.817 202 362.125C203.519 352.199 202 342.042 202 332C206.833 339.833 210.734 348.326 216.5 355.5C221.707 361.978 227.01 360.732 234 361C226.538 348.614 220.272 335.466 215 322C220.643 322.615 227.011 323.708 232 321C226.375 312.292 219.954 304.049 215.125 294.875C211.053 287.14 205.717 277.787 208.5 269.5C215.333 277.5 223.823 284.341 229 293.5C230.73 296.561 228.333 300.5 228 304C231.958 303.792 236.287 301.69 239.875 303.375C246.405 306.442 251.23 312.319 256.406 317.344C257.057 317.976 256.802 319.115 257 320C256.141 319.848 246.574 316.45 244.625 320.375C241.996 325.668 239.101 331.341 239.188 337.25C239.239 340.751 243.063 343.083 245 346C245 340.5 245 340.5 245 335C248.75 336.25 248.75 336.25 252.5 337.5C256.556 331.127 253.519 333.655 263 332C260.75 338.458 256.931 344.57 256.25 351.375C256.016 353.713 259.627 354.818 260.5 357C261.762 360.156 260.364 364.356 262.5 367C264.388 369.337 268.167 369 271 370C270.125 366.854 268.022 363.809 268.375 360.562C268.699 357.584 272.509 355.755 272.875 352.781C273.392 348.583 269.919 344.371 270.875 340.25C271.635 336.975 278.31 332.383 281.5 336.5C284.617 340.522 284.769 346.68 288.625 350C291.418 352.405 295.875 351.333 299.5 352C300.195 361.037 301.139 356.649 296 365C307.887 370.349 305.736 345.51 305.406 343.125C304.187 334.302 288.826 330.941 283 324C291.774 322.375 287.804 321.546 295 326C298.875 322.734 298.875 322.734 302.75 319.469C305.875 322.234 305.875 322.234 309 325C307.612 318.061 303.004 304.117 292.125 306.406C285.71 307.756 280.124 318.025 274.375 314.875C260.287 307.155 247.255 299.206 249 283C232.566 280.902 237.012 264.718 231.625 249.375C226.898 235.911 218.57 223.682 215.344 209.781C214.194 204.827 217.425 197.864 222.216 196.157C227.769 212.438 232.452 229.042 238.875 245C242.328 253.578 248.342 254.4 256 258C251.083 240.75 245.323 223.718 241.25 206.25C240.803 204.333 242.146 202.417 242.594 200.5C254.385 228.073 264.613 256.369 277.969 283.219C283.49 294.318 294.199 292.144 304 293C284.006 264.522 275.251 229.568 263 197C282.917 222.479 301.997 248.635 322.75 273.438C331.108 283.427 344.091 274.901 352 271C325.938 244.194 303.382 214.173 280 185C298.58 198.142 316.443 212.362 335.739 224.428C351.643 234.373 358.103 218.902 364 208C355.896 205.208 346.931 204.208 339.688 199.625C321.369 188.036 304.92 173.704 288.125 160C286.602 158.757 286.042 156.667 285 155C303.875 161.167 322.469 168.272 341.625 173.5C353.216 176.663 361.04 156.397 364 151C339.166 146.764 315.257 137.515 292.25 127.25C290.42 126.434 289.417 124.417 288 123C308.196 125.805 346.101 137.738 362 116.375C365.284 111.962 366 106.125 368 101C338.406 101.51 308.955 101.736 282 87C303.667 87 325.462 89.3591 347 87C351.219 86.5379 354.472 82.3929 356.75 78.8125C361.626 71.151 364.25 62.2708 368 54C344.666 59.4084 320.119 59.5949 296.24 57.72C291.741 57.3667 286.752 56.319 283.471 53.22C280.768 50.6665 282.625 43.8286 279 43C274.148 61.2227 252.903 53.2314 238.475 55.4675C236.915 55.7093 235.959 57.707 235.625 59.25C230.162 84.5018 258.723 104.327 229 122C230.219 113.391 230.219 113.391 231.438 104.781C214.208 101.693 215.936 93.3421 227 83C222.159 81.3521 215.468 76.8958 216.438 71.875C217.468 66.5388 224.583 63.4188 225 58C217.926 57.0569 220.332 58.8815 217.156 53.4688C220.438 49.9792 225.147 47.4171 227 43C228.676 39.0039 227 34.3333 227 30C210.772 45.8511 204.706 20.4146 191 26.5C188.089 27.7927 188.314 33.5116 185.18 34.08C174.913 35.9417 159.82 23.7982 158 42Z}
    ;% ~~~ so is the end ~~~~~~~~~~
    }% end of pic-definition
    ]% end of options
    
    
    \pic[yscale=-1] at ( 0, 0) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1] at (15, 0) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1,rotate=-30,xshift=-10mm] at ( 0,15) {eagl};  
    \pic[yscale=-1,scale=0.3] at (15,15) {eagl};    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to add coloring options for the eagles?

Comment: @Epa, see the P.S., please

Comment: I don't think you want `\include` here as it will start a new page. Did you mean `\input`?

Comment: You are right, of course : )

Answer (score 19):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5]
    \clip(0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);

\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](0,-1)--(0,5);

\draw[line width=9pt, color=yellow!76](-2,2.35)--++(4,0);
    \draw[thick](0,0) .. controls (.15,.35) and (2,-.1).. (2,0.5)--++(0,4)--++(-4,0)--++(0,-4) ..controls(-2,-.1) and(-.15,.35) ..(0,0);

\duck[xshift=-50pt,yshift=15pt,scale=0.7,parrot]
\duck[xshift=-50pt,yshift=75pt,scale=0.7,parrot]
\duck[xshift=7pt,yshift=15pt,scale=0.7,parrot]
\duck[xshift=7pt,yshift=75pt,scale=0.7,parrot]

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Four eagles, disguised as ducks.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Eagles]

I'll get my coat.

Comment: You missed the hair-styling ... https://eagles.com/blogs/news ;-)