How to achieve one point perspective for a given tikz-3dplot?
I am trying to replicate this drawing with tikz-3dplot:


I have already done the main drawing (above, second image), but I cannot achieve the perspective. I tried with the perspective library and some other things I've found on this site, but nothing seems to work.
I know where the vanishing point should be, and that it must be a one-vanishing-point perspective:

How can I modify my code to achieve the perspective, if possible?
I have set \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{10} just to draw efficiently, but the lines parallel to the Y-axis are still parallel with this command, they should converge.
\documentclass[border = 10mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{soul}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\drawcube}[9][]{
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#2) -- (#3) -- (#4) -- (#5) -- cycle; % Bottom face
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#6) -- (#7) -- (#8) -- (#9) -- cycle; % Top face
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#2) -- (#6); 
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#3) -- (#7); 
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#4) -- (#8); 
    \draw[cubo, #1] (#5) -- (#9);
    }

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
            spiral/.style={line width = 1ex},
            helix/.style={line width = 1ex},
            cubo/.style={line width = .5ex},
            quadro/.style={line width = .5ex},
            tdplot_main_coords,
        ]

    % coordinates
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \foreach \v/\i/\j in {1/21/0, 2/21/21, 3/0/21, 4/-13/21, 5/-13/8, 6/-13/0, 7/-5/0, 8/0/0, 9/0/5, 10/0/8, 11/-3/8, 12/-5/8, 13/-5/6, 14/-5/5, 15/-4/5, 16/-3/5, 17/-3/6, 18/-4/6}
        \coordinate (A\v) at ($(O)+(\i,\j,0)$); 

    % spiral
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
        % squares
        \foreach \i/\j in {1/3, 3/5, 5/7, 7/9, 9/11, 11/13}
            \draw[quadro] (A\i) rectangle (A\j);
        % spiral arcs
        \foreach \p/\i/\f/\l in {1/0/90/21, 3/90/180/13, 5/180/270/8, 7/-90/0/5, 9/0/90/3, 11/90/180/2}
            \draw[spiral] (A\p) arc (\i:\f:\l);
        % diagonals
        \draw[name path = BD] (A2) -- (A6);
        \draw[name path = AC] (A4) -- (A8);
        \path[name intersections = {of = AC and BD, by = OO}];
    \end{scope}

    % cubes
        \foreach \v/\i/\j/\k in {
            % cube 21
            1/21/0/0, 2/21/21/0, 3/0/21/0, 4/0/0/0, 5/21/0/21, 6/21/21/21, 7/0/21/21, 8/0/0/21,
            % cube 13
            9/-13/21/21, 10/-13/8/21, 11/0/8/21, 12/0/21/34, 13/-13/21/34, 14/-13/8/34, 15/0/8/34,
            % cubo 8
            16/-13/0/34, 17/-5/0/34, 18/-5/8/34, 19/-13/8/42, 20/-13/0/42, 21/-5/0/42, 22/-5/8/42,
            % cubo 5
            23/0/0/42, 24/0/5/42, 25/-5/5/42, 26/-5/0/47, 27/0/0/47, 28/0/5/47, 29/-5/5/47,
            % cubo 3
            30/0/8/47, 31/-3/8/47, 32/-3/5/47, 33/0/5/50, 34/0/8/50, 35/-3/8/50, 36/-3/5/50,
            % cubo 2
            37/-5/8/50, 38/-5/6/50, 39/-3/6/50, 40/-3/8/52, 41/-5/8/52, 42/-5/6/52, 43/-3/6/52
            }
            \coordinate (C\v) at ($(O)+(\i,\j,\k)$);
            
        \drawcube{C1}{C2}{C3}{C4}{C5}{C6}{C7}{C8}
        \drawcube{C7}{C9}{C10}{C11}{C12}{C13}{C14}{C15}
        \drawcube{C14}{C16}{C17}{C18}{C19}{C20}{C21}{C22}
        \drawcube{C21}{C23}{C24}{C25}{C26}{C27}{C28}{C29}
        \drawcube{C28}{C30}{C31}{C32}{C33}{C34}{C35}{C36}
        \drawcube{C35}{C37}{C38}{C39}{C40}{C41}{C42}{C43}

    % helix 
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 0:90, smooth]
            ({21*cos(\x)},{21*sin(\x)},{(21*(1-cos(\x)+sin(\x)))/2});
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 90:180, smooth]
            ({13*cos(\x)},{13*sin(\x)+8},{(55-13*(cos(\x)+sin(\x)))/2});
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 180:270, smooth]
            ({8*cos(\x)-5},{8*sin(\x)+8},{(76+8*(cos(\x)-sin(\x)))/2});
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 270:360, smooth]
            ({5*cos(\x)-5},{5*sin(\x)+5},{(89+5*(cos(\x)+sin(\x)))/2});
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 0:90, smooth]
            ({3*cos(\x)-3},{3*sin(\x)+5},{(97+3*(-cos(\x)+sin(\x)))/2});
        \draw[helix] plot[domain = 90:180, smooth]
            ({2*cos(\x)-3},{2*sin(\x)+6},{(102-2*(cos(\x)+sin(\x)))/2});

    % labels
        \node[label=below:{\huge $A$}] at (A8){};
        \node[label=left:{\huge $B$}] at (A6){};
        \node[label=above:{\huge $C$}] at (A4){};
        \node[label=right:{\huge $D$}] at (A2){};
        \node[label=above:{\huge $O$}] at (OO){};
        \node[label=right:{\huge $X$}] at ($(C3)!0.5!(C7)$){};
        \node[label=right:{\huge $Y$}] at ($(C7)!0.5!(C12)$){};
        \node[label=right:{\huge $Z$}] at ($(C18)!0.5!(C22)$){};

        \node[align = left, text width = 12cm, anchor = south west, inner sep=0pt] 
                at (5,21,31) 
        {
        \huge
        \begin{tabular}{p{20ex}l}
            \texttt{vertical turns:}   & $\frac{X}{Y} = \frac{Y}{Z} = \phi$\\[1ex]
            \texttt{horizontal turns:} & $\frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{BC}{CD} = \phi$\\[1.5ex]
            \texttt{radius of turns:}  & $\frac{OA}{OB} = \frac{OB}{OC} = \phi$
        \end{tabular}
        };
        \node[align = justify, text width = 18.3cm, anchor = south, inner sep=0pt] at (10,21,38) 
        {
        \Huge
        \textsc{\so{spiral extension of helix}}\\[2ex]
        \LARGE
        \texttt{using the Golden Rectangle plan of `whirling squares' as the geometric basis of a spiral, any of the 5 solids may be substituted for the cube and indicated with a complexity of overlapping forms to articulate polarity within rotation, within polarity - the geometric hierarchies of spiral form. Other proportional series based on the Divine Proportion can be used to define a wide variety of spiral forms. The Divine Proportion progression occurs in the increase or decrease in size of units - the Divine Proportion relation in dimensions of vertical turns, horizontal turns, and radius.}
        };
    
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}

Thank you for your help in advance!

I'm not sure if tikz-3dplot can do one point perspective. What it does is it creates what's called an "orthographic projection." these projections are basically what you'd get if you passed a plane through a 3d object and stored all the points it intersected. Then you'd look at the plane head on and see the orthographic projection of the 3D object. https://www.riansclub.com/orthographic-projection/

To my knowledge transformations with at least one vanishing point are not supported yet. You have to do it "manually" as you tried, or just digitze the coordinates from the magazin. See e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721994/245790 , and here for digitizing https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685905/245790 .

Do you have a formula for the curve in 3d?


I try to answer the question with a code that

uses the library perspective
produces a cube with the faces parallel to the coordinate planes by giving a vertex and the length of the side
produces the approximation of the golden spiral using squares with sides forming the Fibonacci sequence.

The main argument in the code is the number of cubes in the final drawing, \nCubes.  It is introduced on the line 198.  The cube is defined in the preamble as a pic element, cube in perspective.
Remarks

I tried to comment the code and hope it might be sufficient.
There are two parts in the question (and answer), i.e. two different subjects.  The first one concerns the drawing in perspective with one vanishing point.  The main issue here is to understand (be able to use) the observer's position based on the arguments q (and r maybe) the vanishing point, and the azimuth and elevation.  Without the observer's position, one cannot determine when a face of a cube, say, is visible.  I tried to find them, and I think I managed to do it, but only for one vanishing point.  If r is used, problems may occur with the visible faces.  In the images below I avoided them...  In the code, the observer's position is given by the point (\obs{1}, \obs{2}, \obs{3}).  The second is the construction of the approximation of the golden spiral.


I couldn't find the observer's position with two vanishing points p and q.  I might ask a question about it later.

Another image to illustrate how the drawing varies when the number of cubes is different (there are 9 cubes in the first image and 8 in the one below).

The first image with the vertical vanishing point r defined (i'e' a finite point), with different azimuth, and with all the elements shifted to the right.  The code below produces this last image.
The code
\documentclass[11pt, border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  3d coordinate is/.is choice,
  3d coordinate is/default/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointxyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}},
  3d coordinate is/perspective/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{##1{\pgfpointperspectivexyz{##2}{##3}{##4}}}}}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
  1 vp perspective/.style args={azimuth=#1, elevation=#2, q2=#3, r3=#4}{%
    evaluate={%
      \azimuth = #1;
      \elevation = #2;
      \distance = #3;  % does #4 play a role?
      \obs{1} = \distance*tan(\azimuth);
      \obs{2} = -\distance;
      \obs{3} = \distance*tan(\elevation)/cos(\azimuth);
    },  % !!!
    3d view={\azimuth}{\elevation},
    perspective={p={(0, 0, 0)}, q={(0, #3, 0)}, r={(0, 0, #4)}},
    3d coordinate is = perspective
  }
}

%%% cube in perspective
\tikzset{%
  for cubeInP/.style args={anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4}{% 
    evaluate={%
      int \nFaces, \nVOnFace;
      \nFaces = 6;
      \nVOnFace = 4;
    },
    evaluate={%  coordinates of the vertices
      % In the (xy) plane, the points 1, 2, 3, 4 display the direct
      % sens for the basis $(e_x, e_y)$---it is induced by the
      % 3d natural orientation.
      \cCube{1, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{1, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{1, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{2, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{2, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{2, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{3, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{3, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{3, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{4, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{4, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{4, 3} = #3;
      \cCube{5, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{5, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{5, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{6, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{6, 2} = #2;
      \cCube{6, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 1} = #1 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{7, 3} = #3 +#4;
      \cCube{8, 1} = #1;
      \cCube{8, 2} = #2 +#4;
      \cCube{8, 3} = #3 +#4;      
    },
    evaluate={%  indices of vertices for each face and unitary nornal v
      \fRPolyh{1, 1} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{1, 2} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{1, 3} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{1, 4} = 1;
      \nCube{1, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{1, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{1, 3} = -1;
      \fRPolyh{2, 1} = 1;
      \fRPolyh{2, 2} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{2, 3} = 6;
      \fRPolyh{2, 4} = 5;
      \nCube{2, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{2, 2} = -1;
      \nCube{2, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{3, 1} = 2;
      \fRPolyh{3, 2} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{3, 3} = 7;
      \fRPolyh{3, 4} = 6;
      \nCube{3, 1} = 1;
      \nCube{3, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{3, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{4, 1} = 3;
      \fRPolyh{4, 2} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{4, 3} = 8;
      \fRPolyh{4, 4} = 7;
      \nCube{4, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{4, 2} = 1;
      \nCube{4, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{5, 1} = 4;
      \fRPolyh{5, 2} = 1;
      \fRPolyh{5, 3} = 5;
      \fRPolyh{5, 4} = 8;
      \nCube{5, 1} = -1;
      \nCube{5, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{5, 3} = 0;
      \fRPolyh{6, 1} = 5;
      \fRPolyh{6, 2} = 6;
      \fRPolyh{6, 3} = 7;
      \fRPolyh{6, 4} = 8;
      \nCube{6, 1} = 0;
      \nCube{6, 2} = 0;
      \nCube{6, 3} = 1;
    },
    evaluate={%  coordinates of isobarycenters of faces (needed for
              %  opacity and color)
      int \f, \j;
      for \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
        \dx = 0; \dy = 0; \dz = 0;
        for \j in {1, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
          \dx = \dx + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 1};
          \dy = \dy + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 2};
          \dz = \dz + \cCube{\fRPolyh{\f, \j}, 3};
        };
        \dCube{\f, 1} = \dx/\nVOnFace;
        \dCube{\f, 2} = \dy/\nVOnFace;
        \dCube{\f, 3} = \dz/\nVOnFace;      
      };
    },
    evaluate={%  vertices
      coordinate \A{1}, \A{2}, \A{3}, \A{4}, \A{5}, \A{6}, \A{7}, \A{8};
      \A{1} = (\cCube{1, 1}, \cCube{1, 2}, \cCube{1, 3});
      \A{2} = (\cCube{2, 1}, \cCube{2, 2}, \cCube{2, 3});
      \A{3} = (\cCube{3, 1}, \cCube{3, 2}, \cCube{3, 3});
      \A{4} = (\cCube{4, 1}, \cCube{4, 2}, \cCube{4, 3});
      \A{5} = (\cCube{5, 1}, \cCube{5, 2}, \cCube{5, 3});
      \A{6} = (\cCube{6, 1}, \cCube{6, 2}, \cCube{6, 3});
      \A{7} = (\cCube{7, 1}, \cCube{7, 2}, \cCube{7, 3});
      \A{8} = (\cCube{8, 1}, \cCube{8, 2}, \cCube{8, 3});
    },
    evaluate={%  seen and unseen faces
      int \i;
      real \tmp;
      for \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
        \tmp = 0;
        for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%
          \tmp = \tmp +\nCube{\f, \i}*(\obs{\i} -\dCube{\f, \i});
        };
        if \tmp>0 then {\isSeen{\f} = int(1);} else {\isSeen{\f} = int(-1);};
      };
    }
  },
  pics/face cubeinP/.style args={face=#1, color=#2}{% not used here
    code={%
      \draw[#2] (\A{\fRPolyh{#1, 1}})
      \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
        -- (\A{\fRPolyh{#1, \i}})
      } -- cycle;
    }
  },
  pics/cube in perspective/.style args={%
    anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4, color=#5}{%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        \lwS = 1pt;
        \lwU = .6;
      }
      \begin{scope}[for cubeInP={anchor=(#1, #2, #3), side=#4}]
        \foreach \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
          \ifthenelse{\isSeen{\f}<0}{%
            \draw[#5!40, line width=\lwU]
            [preaction={fill=white, opacity=.55}] % !!!
            (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, 1}})
            \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
              -- (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, \i}})
            } -- cycle;
          }{}
        }
        \foreach \f in {1, ..., \nFaces}{%
          \ifthenelse{\isSeen{\f}>0}{%
            \draw[#5, line width=\lwS]
            (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, 1}})
            \foreach \i in {2, ..., \nVOnFace}{%
              -- (\A{\fRPolyh{\f, \i}})
            } -- cycle;
          }{}
        }
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\tikzmath{% moving frame for the squares and cubes later
          % (\PGS; \uGS, \vGS, \wGS) 
  int \nCubes, \nSteps;
  \nCubes = 9;
  \nSteps = 30;
  int \i, \j, \k, \l;
  \w = .15*9/\nCubes;  % the scaling
  \aGS{-1} = 0;
  \aGS{0} = 1;  % Fibonacci sequence
  \sGS{0} = \aGS{0};  % sum of the Fibonacci sequence
  \uGS{0, 1} = \w;  % (u, v) base -> next square
  \uGS{0, 2} = 0;
  \uGS{0, 3} = 0;
  \vGS{0, 1} = 0;
  \vGS{0, 2} = \w;
  \vGS{0, 3} = 0;
  \wGS{1} = 0;
  \wGS{2} = 0;
  \wGS{3} = \w;
  % \PGS main point -> next square
  \PGS{0, 1} = \w +5;  % 5 gives the shift
  \PGS{0, 2} = 5;
  \PGS{0, 3} = 0;
  for \k in {1, ..., \nCubes}{%
    \j = int(\k -1);
    \i = int(\j -1);
    \aGS{\k} = \aGS{\j} +\aGS{\i};
    \sGS{\k} = \sGS{\j} +\aGS{\k};
    for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
      \uGS{\k, \l} = \vGS{\j, \l};
    };
    \vGS{\k, 1} = -\uGS{\k, 2};
    \vGS{\k, 2} = \uGS{\k, 1};
    \vGS{\k, 3} = \uGS{\k, 3};
    for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
      \PGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\j, \l} +\aGS{\k}*\uGS{\j, \l}
      +\aGS{\k}*\vGS{\j, \l};
    };
  };
}
\tikzmath{%  \CGS center of the quarter circle in each square
  int \i, \j, \k, \l;
    for \k in {1, ..., \nCubes}{%
    \j = \k -1;
    for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
      \CGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\j, \l} +\aGS{\k}*\vGS{\j, \l};
    };
  };
}
\tikzmath{%  \MGS the achor of the cube in the
          % square-cube correspondence;
          % it depends on the step modulo 4
  int \i, \j, \k, \l;
  for \k in {1, ..., \nCubes}{%
    \j = \k -1;
    if int(mod(\k, 4))==1 then {%
      for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
        \MGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\j, \l} +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\k})*\wGS{\l};
      };
    };
    if int(mod(\k, 4))==2 then {%
      for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
        \MGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\j, \l}
        +\aGS{\k}*\vGS{\j, \l} +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\k})*\wGS{\l};
      };
    };
    if int(mod(\k, 4))==3 then {%
      for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
        \MGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\k, \l} +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\k})*\wGS{\l};
      };
    };
    if int(mod(\k, 4))==0 then {%
      for \l in {1, 2, 3}{%
        \MGS{\k, \l} = \PGS{\j, \l}
        +\aGS{\k}*\uGS{\j, \l} +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\k})*\wGS{\l};
      };
    };
  };
}

% the drawing
\begin{tikzpicture}[evaluate={%
    \b = 30;
    \c = -60;
  }, 
  1 vp perspective={azimuth=0, elevation=45, q2=\b, r3=\c},
  line cap=round,
  rounded corners=.3]

  % the squares and the approximation (polyline 
  \tikzmath{%
    integer \i, \j, \k, \m, \n;
    for \k in {1, ..., \nCubes}{%
      \j = int{\k -1};
      for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%  B and D are the points in [A, B, C, D] square
        \tmpB{\i} = \PGS{\j, \i} +\aGS{\k}*\uGS{\j, \i};
        \tmpD{\i} = \PGS{\j, \i} +\aGS{\k}*\vGS{\j, \i};
      };
      {%  squares
        \draw[blue!60!black]
        (\PGS{\j, 1}, \PGS{\j, 2}, \PGS{\j, 3})
        -- (\tmpB{1}, \tmpB{2}, \tmpB{3}) 
        -- (\PGS{\k, 1}, \PGS{\k, 2}, \PGS{\k, 3})
        -- (\tmpD{1}, \tmpD{2}, \tmpD{3}) -- cycle;
      };
      for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%  approximation
        \tmpP{0, \i} = \CGS{\k, \i}
        +\aGS{\k}*(cos(-90)*\uGS{\j, \i} +sin(-90)*\vGS{\j, \i});
      };
      for \n in {1, 2, ..., \nSteps}{%
        \m = int(\n -1);
        \t = -90 +3*\n;
        for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%
          \tmpP{\n, \i} = \CGS{\k, \i}
          +\aGS{\k}*(cos(\t)*\uGS{\j, \i} +sin(\t)*\vGS{\j, \i});
        };
        {%
          \draw[red, very thick] (\tmpP{\m, 1}, \tmpP{\m, 2}, \tmpP{\m, 3})
          -- (\tmpP{\n, 1}, \tmpP{\n, 2}, \tmpP{\n, 3});
        };
      };
    };
  }
  % the lifted approximation curve
  % in the z direction it describes a uniform vertical movement
  % controled by the number of segments (\nSteps) of the polyline
  \tikzmath{%
    for \k in {1, 2, ..., \nCubes}{%
      \j = int{\k -1};
      \tmpSide = \w*\aGS{\k};
      for \i in {1, 2, 3}{% 
        \tmpP{0, \i} = \CGS{\k, \i}
        +\aGS{\k}*(cos(-90)*\uGS{\j, \i} +sin(-90)*\vGS{\j, \i})
        +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\j})*\wGS{\i};
      };
      for \n in {1, 2, ..., \nSteps}{%
        \m = int(\n -1);
        \t = -90 +3*\n;
        for \i in {1, 2, 3}{%
          \tmpP{\n, \i} = \CGS{\k, \i}
          +\aGS{\k}*(cos(\t)*\uGS{\j, \i} +sin(\t)*\vGS{\j, \i})
          +(\sGS{\nCubes} -\sGS{\j} -\n/\nSteps*\aGS{\k})*\wGS{\i};
        };
        {%
          \draw[red!60!black, very thick]
          (\tmpP{\m, 1}, \tmpP{\m, 2}, \tmpP{\m, 3})
          -- (\tmpP{\n, 1}, \tmpP{\n, 2}, \tmpP{\n, 3});
        };
      };
    };
  }
  % % the cubes
  \tikzmath{%
    for \k in {\nCubes, ..., 1}{%
      \tmpSide = \w*\aGS{\k};
      {%
        \path (0, 0) pic
        {cube in perspective={anchor=(\MGS{\k, 1}, \MGS{\k, 2}, \MGS{\k, 3}),
            side=\tmpSide, color=blue!60!black}};
      };
    };
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


